# Android - Animation offset - How to prevent the view from being drawn while the offset has not yet passed?

Tags: android, animation, view, offset

I am trying to start an animation AFTER 1 second. I have used the attribute *"android:startOffset"* in my XML file, but it does not work completely the way I expected. I was expecting the view to NOT EVEN BE DRAW in its initial position (that is, the position set in the attributes "*fromXDelta*" and "*fromYDelta*") before the offset I set has passed. Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:ordering="sequentially"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

  <translate
      android:duration="2000"
      android:startOffset="1000"
      android:fromXDelta="-70%p"
      android:fromYDelta="0%p"
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
      android:toXDelta="+0%p"
      android:toYDelta="0%p" />

</set>
```

If I try to move my view using the above animation, the view is drawn IMMEDIATELY at the position -70% of the screen. Then the one second passes and then, as expected, the animation kicks in and starts to move the view. However, **I DO NOT want the view to be drawn at all before that 1 second!**. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

### UPDATE

I am calling the above XML just after a startActivity call (the *R.anim.animation_coming_in* below), like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, ThankYouActivity.class)); 
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_coming_in, R.anim.animation_coming_out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a pair of `alpha` animations with very short duration so that the view is hidden until it's needed. Something like this:

```
<set ...>
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="1"
        android:startOffset="0" />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="1"
        android:startOffset="1000" />
    <translate
        ...
    />
</set>
```

Alternatively, you could implement this set of animations in code. Doing so would enable you to use a `Handler` to start the animation after a delay so that the view is hidden until the animation starts.

Comment: Hi acj, thank you for replying. I tried your XML solution and it did work. I have also tried to play around with the alpha values (tried with one and with two alpha tags) and nothing seems to work... I would like a solution using only XML. There must be some, I just can't find it.

Comment: @TiagoT When you tried the alpha method, what behavior did you see? Also, do you have any other animations that are happening concurrently with this one?

Comment: The screen turned completely black and, after 1 second, the view showed up already on its final place. And yes, I am running a concurrent animation. Actually, I am trying to do this animation in the overridePendingTransition method, just after the startActivity call. The XML above is the first parameter (that is, the activity's view that is coming to the screen).

Comment: I have updated my question with that information as well. Thank you again acj.